# How to disable search menu animation in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

The search menu (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) plays a "sliding" animation when opened and when typing or clearing the search field.

I have disabled animations in performance options (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, enter `sysdm.cpl` > advanced > settings under "performance" > visual effects ):

[image: performance options]

"Play animations in Windows" setting is disabled in ease of access (Windows 10 settings app):

[image: settings app]

Comment: You would have to use one of the many start menu replacement applications to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Ramhound: You can share suitable software if you're sure there's no other way.

Comment: Questions seeking software recommendations are not within scope.